# Automate log in to a website with Python 3.5 & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently trying to open the login page, which is '', to fill in the 'username' and 'password' fields, and then click on 'sign in', all done automatically with Python and Selenium.

But I can't even fill in the first text form, which is the username.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
user = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'userid')))

user.clear()
user.send_keys('myemail@mail.com')
```

This gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/michael/PycharmProjects/project/doc.py", line 10, in 
>       user = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'userid')))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
>       raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

How can I fill in these 2 forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fld")
elements[2].send_keys("username")
elements[3].send_keys("password")

button = driver.find_element_by_id("sgnBt")
button.click()
```

Comment: thank you so much! would you mind explain me how to click on the 'sign in' button ?  i tried **buttons = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sgnBtn')** followed by **buttons[0].click()** but it doesnt work and give me **TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing** thanks

Comment: added the code to the answer. I'm glad that was helpful, please consider marking the answer as helpful to close the topic